# How do I debug a Unity Container "Resolve"?

Tags: inversion-of-control, unity-container

I'm using the MS Unity container to do dependency injection, but a "Resolve" is returning unexpected results.

Is there an way I can debug this resolution? It would be great if I could view what Types/Instances are registered in the container, but I can't see where this is stored when using QuickWatch. It would also be useful if I could get the container to output some debug Traces.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can I suggest to post more details about that unexpected result and some code sample? Maybe someone can point you where is the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source code for the Unity framework is available for download at http://unity.codeplex.com. If you include it in your solution and reference the Unity projects instead of the compiled DLLs in your projects, you will be able to debug through the Unity source code.